# Can ElasticSearch do fuzzy aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

For example I have two docs such as: `doc1={"ename":"pop2 up3 donw1"}, doc2={"ename":"up3 pop2"}`. Because they looks similar, I wanna they can be aggregated to one item by field ename. So I called it Fuzzy Aggregation.Does ES have the above feature please.